# Is it bad if I download to an SSD and move to an external HDD later?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I know that downloading stuff (such as movies) to an SSD is a bad thing; but if I download them there first and then move them to an external hard disk drive is it a bad thing?

Comment: Downloading a file to an SSD isn't a bad thing.  Who told you such a ridiculous statement?

Comment: SSD life is often expressed as Terra Bytes Written (TBW) after which they might start to fail. You should know what's the documented TBW stated by the manufacturer for your SSD. Optimizing the number of writes is one way to expect a much longer life of SSD. Practically for an SSD with 75 TBW assuming you write 40 GB / day it might fail after about 5 years.  Basically by downloading movies (much larger files sized in GBs) on to SSD you are consuming its Write Cycles.

Comment: I have a 256GB SSD and I sometimes write movies on it(average size of each movie Is 1.5GB). Will it hurt my SSD's lifespan in any considerable way or I shouldn't be bothered with this issue?

Answer (score 8):

If you're worried about the life of your SSD, if it is a fairly modern model you shouldn't have any issue.

For example a few months ago techreport [did a test with modern SSDs](http://techreport.com/review/27436/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-two-freaking-petabytes).
In the test the SSDs died after writing at least 700TB up to more that 2PB.
If you plan to write about 100GB per day on your disk it means at least 20 years of life.

Comment: SSD != *"disk"*.  It's a drive.

Comment: you're right, fixed

Comment: @MarcoRighele You said 700GB, but did you mean 750TB? From the article they mention "Ours took its own life after 750TB". That would make a pretty big difference as 700GB is really not that much if you are constantly downloading movies.

Comment: Sorry, I should pay attention to what I write. Yes, of course I mean 700TB, I will fix the typo

Comment: @sawdust So what is it driving????

Comment: I have a 256GB SSD and I sometimes write movies on it(average size of each movie Is 1.5GB). Will it hurt my SSD's lifespan in any considerable way or I shouldn't be bothered with this issue?

Comment: @Superbest -- In a SSD, nothing; there's not even a motor.  It's simply a reuse of terminology to associate new technology (or new application of existing tech) with an existing device (i.e. HDD) to promote substitution/replacement.  Solid state mass-storage device does not mean too much to non-professionals.   See http://superuser.com/questions/341497/whats-the-difference-between-a-disk-and-a-drive

Comment: Well I like to call it disk lol otherwise nobody knows what I'm talking about haha...

Comment: @MarcoRighele what about my case?

Answer (score 5):

It first depends on your definition of 'bad'. ..but if that definition is 'anytime I write to my SSD' then it makes no difference whatsoever whether you keep it on the SSD or move it somewhere else afterwards.

Of course, you could skip the entire 'danger' scenario, if you feel the need, & save it to the external in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To the essence of the question: If you believe that downloading to an SSD is bad because of write cycle issues...then downloading to an SSD and moving to an HDD will not make any difference at all. Consider that the data still has to be written to the SSD in the first place, before it is then moved off to the HDD.

However, as other posters have said, unless you're doing some type of massive data-logging application (example: surveillance cameras) where you're writing hundreds of gigabytes per day to your SSD, then you're highly unlikely to actually wear out your SSD in the near or even somewhat distant future.