# I'm confused about what a driver exactly is

Tags: hard-drive, usb, drivers, dvd

Alright, so from what I know so far a disk drive is a common type of secondary storage memory. In my book, it says a disk drive stores data by magnetically encoding it onto a circular disk. There are embedded disk drives and external ones that connect through communication ports. Floppy disks are one type of outdated disk drives in favor of USB's which are memory sticks that are recognized by a computer as a disk drive. It then cells optical disks like CD's and DVD's are popular for data storage, and CD and DVD drives read them. So, I'm a bit confused. I was originally under the impression a drive is a disk or USB that stores data so that it can be stored or transported. Now, it's saying CD and DVD drives read information with lasers; that alone confuses me since I'm unsure if optical devices are drives in themselves or just optical drives. It didn't say if there was a difference. When I looked it up, I got a couple different things. One said a drive was a program and one showed a CD and DVD drive as a CD player (which confused me more since I thought a CD player would be considered hardware). I'm also confused about if CD's and DVD's can act as a secondary memory storage (though I'm not sure since I'm not sure if all secondary memory storage has to come in drives and if optical devices are drives). Some in-depth clarification would be great. I'm dying here and the people that do know about computers have somehow managed to confuse me more or weren't sure themselves, haha.

BTW, I'm also confused about what a hard drive is. When I look it up, a CD and DVD player also pops up. It says a hard disk drive (sometimes abbreviated as Hard drive, HD, or HDD) is a non-volatile memory hardware device that permanently stores and retrieves information. Would a disk drive like a floppy disk be considered a hard drive?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/341497/whats-the-difference-between-a-disk-and-a-drive/341579#341579

Answer (score 2):

> I'm confused about what a driver exactly is

it's nothing to do with a hard drive.  It's a different subject.

> Alright, so from what I know so far a disk drive is a common type of
>   secondary storage memory.

well, do you really know.. do you know what the difference between primary memory and secondary memory is.

> In my book, it says a disk drive stores data
>   by magnetically encoding it onto a circular disk.

Well you said a USB is a disk drive, and you should know that doesn't operate like that, so your book is wrong.

The original disk drives work like that, spinning disk, and people still use those today as they are higher capacity for the same price, than solid state drives.

Also as you later suggest..  cd/dvd drives don't use magnetic disks.  A cd/dvd might contain some metal but it's not considered to be a magnetic disk.

> There are embedded
>   disk drives and external ones that connect through communication
>   ports.

well, there are internal ones and external ones, and loads of internal drives plug into a motherboard thus communicate through a communication port.

> Floppy disks are one type of outdated disk drives in favor of
>   USB's which are memory sticks that are recognized by a computer as a
>   disk drive.

well, don't confuse a disk with a disk drive.

a floppy disk goes into a floppy disk drive.

> It then cells

I think you mean says.

> optical disks like CD's and DVD's are
>   popular for data storage, and CD and DVD drives read them. So, I'm a
>   bit confused.
>
> I was originally under the impression a drive is a disk
>   or USB that stores data so that it can be stored or transported. Now,
>   it's saying CD and DVD drives read information with lasers; that alone
>   confuses me since
>
> I'm unsure if optical devices are drives in
>   themselves or just optical drives.

That question isn't that clear logically.  You are not sure if As are Bs in themselves or just some type of Bs.

You can have magnetic disk drives,  and optical disk drives.  They are different types of disk drives.

Often in the optical case people write disc, and in the magnetic case people write disk.

And solid state drives aren't have a disk/disc at all, or a thing driving a disk/disc. But the term disk drive has stuck.

> It didn't say if there was a
>   difference. When I looked it up, I got a couple different things. One
>   said a drive was a program

no.. maybe a driver is to an extent but it's more of a library of code, and drivers have almost nothing at all to do with drives specifically. Lots of hardware requires drivers which is software.  (it's really really rare that you have to install a driver for a disk drive maybe some RAID drives.. or some weird thing to get an old windows version to recognize a rewritable cd or something). Printers need drivers, and to get a printer working you almost always have to install a driver.

I don't know much about drivers, but drivers are pieces of software that hardware use to communicate with the operating system.

> and one showed a CD and DVD drive as a CD
>   player (which confused me more since I thought a CD player would be
>   considered hardware). I'm also confused about if CD's and DVD's can
>   act as a secondary memory storage (though I'm not sure since I'm not
>   sure if all secondary memory storage has to come in drives and if
>   optical devices are drives).

that's all secondary storage.

The books basically call  hard disk drives secondary storage.. probably optical disk drives they'd call secondary storage.  And they call RAM primary storage.

> Some in-depth clarification would be
>   great. I'm dying here and the people that do know about computers have
>   somehow managed to confuse me more or weren't sure themselves, haha.
>
> BTW, I'm also confused about what a hard drive is. When I look it up,
>   a CD and DVD player also pops up. It says a hard disk drive (sometimes
>   abbreviated as Hard drive, HD, or HDD) is a non-volatile memory
>   hardware device that permanently stores and retrieves information.
>   Would a disk drive like a floppy disk be considered a hard drive?

In the case of a hard disk drive, nobody takes the disk out of it.  They could though then it won't work.  So you can talk of a hard disk drive storing things.

But in the case of a floppy disk drive, you don't say a floppy disk drive stores things. It's the disk in the floppy disk drive that stores things and you can hit the eject button and remove or change the disk.

All disks are non-volatile..

RAM is volatile.

The difference between a floppy disk and a hard disk is that  and you see this if you break open a floppy disk, it's floppy. And a hard disk drive if you unscrew it you'll see the disk is hard.    And also prior to 3.5" floppy disks you had 5.25" floppy disks and even in their plastic casing they were floppy. And of course a hard disk stores much more data than the outdated floppy disk.

Comment: *"In the case of a hard disk drive, nobody takes the disk out of it."* -- Before there were PCs, computers used disk drives with removable platters.  E.g. SMD means [Storage Module Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_Module_Device), a disk drive for a Storage Module, aka a 14" disk pack.  *"RAM is volatile."*  -- False, it's implementation specific.  There is no volatility attribute attached to RAM.  It's semiconductor memory such as DRAM that is in common use for RAM which is volatile.  Older computers used ferrite core for RAM, and it is non-volatile.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks. How would you define the difference between primary and secondary storage?  (anything besides that primary is quicker than secondary?)

Comment: Thanks, Barlop. This was a big help. You said that loads of internal drives plug into a motherboard thus communicate through a communication port.

Are you saying that both external and internal drives that communicate with communication ports? 

Also, what's a motherboard? Is an internal drive always connected to it?

Comment: Sawdust, what is the difference between volatile, non-volatile, and flash memory?

Comment: @FBHSIE It's difficult to even think of a computer that doesn't have an internal drive that plugs in.U can be 100% sure that your laptop or big computer, whether bought now or 30 years ago,if it has an internal hard drive(which it usually will),that internal hard drive,plugs in/out.   You can start a computer up without a hard drive,so a computer doesn't have to have a hard drive connected to it. A motherboard is a board that has the main chips of a computer soldered on and other main parts e.g. hard drives,cd drives,connected to it with cables. You could open a computer case up and you'll see

Comment: @FBHSIE if you ever get somebody round to put a new hard drive in your computer or to fix it in any way, I suggest you ask them to open it up and show you around

Comment: @FBHSIE you also get things plugged into the motherboard like lego.

Comment: *"difference between primary and secondary storage"* -- I'm not accustomed to using that terminology; it's ambiguous.I don't recall what was used in college courses, but professionally RAM and mass storage are used more often.  Speed and cost are the salient issues, and dictate the implemented interfaces.  RAM (which is integral to the architecture of the computer) has to provide instructions and data to the CPU, so there's a (local) bus interface.  Mass storage is accessed using I/O (or memory-mapped I/O) instructions, and are peripherals (i.e. separate from the CPU+memory).