# The tell-tale for a drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, operating-systems

In one of the answers to my last question which was seeking for the exact definitions of the terms "drive" and "partitions" :

[Some basic things like drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1288633/some-basic-things-like-drive)

It was mentioned that "Windows automatically mounts any drive that it finds"

So , it made me curious to ask the following question :

1. How does window detect "a drive" . Or what exactly does Window( and for that matter any other OS) agree to as the definition of a drive ?
2. Is there any signature pattern of bits that it looks for so as to identify a drive , just like the BIOS looks for the magic numbers at the last three bytes of a sector so as to know that it a bootable sector ?

Comment: “Drive” is strictly a Windows term. It refers to drive letters (like `C:`).

Comment: Unfortunately you're asking for clarification of a IMO low-quality answer.

Comment: Relevant:  see https://superuser.com/questions/341497/whats-the-difference-between-a-disk-and-a-drive  BTW you and @DanielB are conflating "drive" with "logical drive".

Comment: You need to study the  [Master Boot Record, MBR](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976786.aspx).  MBR and boot sectors have a signature of two, not three, bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Windows would detect a drive like any OS - it has a driver built in which looks at the SATA (or whatever) interfaces and queries it for drive details. Basically a drive is something the OS knows of and the device provides appropriate size details.

As I believe you are aware, the drive is broken down into partitions. The OS reads the raw drive and locates the information on the partitions, which is generally in a known standard - typically MBR or GPT - which is stored at a known location near the start of the drive.

Typically the partition is formatted with a filesystem - OS's typically use the signature bytes associated with a filesystem to work out how to mount it. (It is also possible to set hints of thr filesystem type in the partition info - this can be handy for booting some complex partition formats - like software RAID, but is not always accurate and specific)

(I'm not sure where you get the idea of bootable sectors from - I'm pretty sure thats not correct) although partitions information can include a bootable bit to indicate if the partition is bootable - likewise information for if the disk is bootable can be stored in the first sector. (This info can also be stored in BIOS on newer GPT based systems)

Comment: You’re right: In a legacy BIOS boot, the first block (containing the MBR) on hard disk/SSD is loaded into memory and executed. Nothing more, nothing less. No magic is involved. What happens next is up to the code stored in the MBR. That also involves dealing with the “bootable” flag and whatnot.

Comment: @Davidgo : Would be glad to know my misconceptions about bootable sector .

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as a "bootable sectors" (which implies any sector/more then 1 can be bootable). There is a single "boot sector" at the beginning of a bootable disk, but this need not have any "magic bytes" at the end (but I see it sometimes does on some OS's)

Comment: The first sector of a x86 HDD is the Master Boot Record.  "Master" implies subordinate records.  And there are.  Every partition can have a boot sector in its first sector.  All such boot sectors have a two-byte signature.

Comment: @davidgo : The two comments above are seemingly contradicting . As one of them asserts the necessity of "magic bytes " and another negates this necessity .

Comment: @sawdust : My main question was about "How is a partition detected ? "

Comment: It appears I am wrong with respect of "magic bytes" (ie 55AA)  https://neosmart.net/wiki/mbr-boot-process/ has an in-depth view of how the boot process works (at least for Linux) - and the 55AA signature at bytes 511 and 512 is used by BIOS's to check if the disk is bootable.

Comment: @AmigorustBurrough *"My main question ..."* -- I answered that (and more) in your original post: https://superuser.com/questions/1288633/some-basic-things-like-drive/1289855#1289855

Comment: @sawdust : Went through your detailed answer , please find some more questions in the edited post . Thanks a lot .