# Installing SSD and non-SSD HDs cause system freeze

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, multi-boot

SSD harddisk hosting windows 10 works fine when alone (the only HD). But, connecting the 2nd non-SSD harddisk hosting Ubuntu (in a dual-boot configuration) causes issues for BOTH windows and Ubuntu installations:  long freezes of about 10 seconds which goes away by itself but comes back again randomly.
Removing the second non-SSD harddisk returns everything to normal and windows on the first SSD harddisk works smoothly again.
It seems like for some reason these two hard disks cannot coexist in my system.

Diagnostic software show no issue in any of the hard disks, by the way.

Any idea why?

My config: MB Gigabyte GA-MA770T-UD3P (rev 1.0), CPU AMD Phenom II X4 B50, RAM Corsair CM3X, HD1 SSD GEIL Zenith R3 (hosting win 10), HD2 WD Caviar Black (hosting Ubuntu), GPU NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti

Comment: When it happens next time on Windows 10, just check if any System or Application level Event (Some error) is logged into Windows Event Viewer and check if anything can be derived from it. What diagnostic software did you use to check the Health? Was it some proprietary manufacturer provided e.g. by WD or some third party tool? Also what if you plug in only the Ubuntu HDD in your system? Does WD HDD only works fine?

Comment: *"SSD harddisk"* and *"non-SSD harddisk"* are nonsense phrases.  There are SSDs and HHDs.  Instead of *"harddisk'*, the collective term you are looking for to encompass both is *storage drive* (or simply *drive*).  See https://superuser.com/questions/341497/whats-the-difference-between-a-disk-and-a-drive

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I couldn't find a better phrase to distinguish the two

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your input. I was lucky that the issue was resolved after a default reset of the bios. AHCI settings were returned to IDE default. AHCI was to blame, it seems. Performance impact is unnoticeable. Thank you again. Cheers